# spring-boot:3.2.1 (spring-security-config:6.2.1) Upgrade Issue: Error Creating Bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

#### Configuration:

I have a Spring Boot application with the following security configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        httpRequests -> httpRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

#### Description:

This configuration worked successfully with Spring Boot 3.2.0 (`org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:6.2.0`). However, after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.1, which includes `org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:6.2.1`, the application fails to start, and I encounter the following error:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:322) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:310) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.learn.security.SecurityApplication.main(SecurityApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:111) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:319) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find FilterChainProxy in [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector$$Lambda$877/0x000000080148a940@3fde2209, org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter@1f916219]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.findFilterChainProxy(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:302) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.<init>(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:214) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:210) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

#### Additional Information:

I noticed that the issue is related to changes in the `WebMvcSecurityConfiguration` class in `spring-security-config:6.2.1`. For reference, I have provided sample projects for both Spring Boot `3.2.0` and `3.2.1`:

- Spring Boot 3.2.0: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/stackoverflow/tree/sb_3_2_0/security)
- Spring Boot 3.2.1: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kcsurapaneni/stackoverflow/tree/sb_3_2_1/security)

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully start the Spring Boot application.

Comment: i belive this is the bug, if you remove the Debug flag see if it works then https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14370

Comment: @Toerktumlare , you're correct. The error is caused by having `debug=true`. It appears that a fix has already been committed and will be included in the upcoming release `spring-security-config:6.1.7`. The same fix should also be available in `spring-security-config:6.2.2`. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: extends to usage of `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.debugEnabled`

Comment: It looks like the bug appears also on Spring Boot 3.1.7 (`org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.1.6`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. You can wait for the official fix. If you are in a hurry, you can use the following temporary solution.

```
 @Bean
    static BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {
        return registry -> registry.getBeanDefinition(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME).setBeanClassName(CompositeFilterChainProxy.class.getName());
    }

static class CompositeFilterChainProxy extends FilterChainProxy {

        private final Filter doFilterDelegate;

        private final FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

        CompositeFilterChainProxy(List<? extends Filter> filters) {
            this.doFilterDelegate = createDoFilterDelegate(filters);
            this.springSecurityFilterChain = findFilterChainProxy(filters);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.afterPropertiesSet();
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            this.doFilterDelegate.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Filter> getFilters(String url) {
            return this.springSecurityFilterChain.getFilters(url);
        }

        @Override
        public List<SecurityFilterChain> getFilterChains() {
            return this.springSecurityFilterChain.getFilterChains();
        }

        @Override
        public void setSecurityContextHolderStrategy(SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy) {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.setSecurityContextHolderStrategy(securityContextHolderStrategy);
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilterChainValidator(FilterChainValidator filterChainValidator) {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.setFilterChainValidator(filterChainValidator);
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilterChainDecorator(FilterChainDecorator filterChainDecorator) {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.setFilterChainDecorator(filterChainDecorator);
        }

        @Override
        public void setFirewall(HttpFirewall firewall) {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.setFirewall(firewall);
        }

        @Override
        public void setRequestRejectedHandler(RequestRejectedHandler requestRejectedHandler) {
            this.springSecurityFilterChain.setRequestRejectedHandler(requestRejectedHandler);
        }

        private static Filter createDoFilterDelegate(List<? extends Filter> filters) {
            CompositeFilter delegate = new CompositeFilter();
            delegate.setFilters(filters);
            return delegate;
        }

        private static FilterChainProxy findFilterChainProxy(List<? extends Filter> filters) {
            for (Filter filter : filters) {
                if (filter instanceof FilterChainProxy fcp ) {
                    return fcp;
                }
                if (filter instanceof DebugFilter debugFilter ) {
                    return debugFilter.getFilterChainProxy();
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't find FilterChainProxy in " + filters);
        }

    }
```

Comment: do you mind sharing the issue link? if it's already created